# Scraping projects urls from Kickstarter using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape projects' URLs from the [Kickstarter webpage](https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/advanced?category_id=28&staff_picks=1&sort=newest&seed=2639586&page=1) using Beautiful Soup. I am using the following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/advanced?category_id=28&staff_picks=1&sort=newest&seed=2639586&page=1'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

project_name_list = soup.find(class_='grid-row flex flex-wrap')

project_name_list_items = project_name_list.find_all('a')
print(project_name_list_items)

for project_name in project_name_list_items:
    links = project_name.get('href')
    print(links)
```

But this is what I get as output:

```
[<a class="block img-placeholder w100p"><div class="img-placeholder bg-grey-400 absolute t0 w100p"></div></a>, <a class="block img-placeholder w100p"><div class="img-placeholder bg-grey-400 absolute t0 w100p"></div></a>, <a class="block img-placeholder w100p"><div class="img-placeholder bg-grey-400 absolute t0 w100p"></div></a>, <a class="block img-placeholder w100p"><div class="img-placeholder bg-grey-400 absolute t0 w100p"></div></a>, <a class="block img-placeholder w100p"><div class="img-placeholder bg-grey-400 absolute t0 w100p"></div></a>, <a class="block img-placeholder w100p"><div class="img-placeholder bg-grey-400 absolute t0 w100p"></div></a>]
None
None
None
None
None
None
```

I tried several ways, such as:

```
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

But still no results.
Also, this page that I am scraping has a "Load more" part at the end of the page. How can I get the URLs in that part?
I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data is not embedded in the html itself but as JSON in an html attribute called `data-project`. One solution is to use a `find_all("div")` and check out only those that have that attribute

Also while the url is present in JSON, there is a query parameter named `ref` that is present in another html attribute called `data-ref`. The following get all the links for page 1

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

url = 'https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/advanced?category_id=28&staff_picks=1&sort=newest&seed=2639586&page=1'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

data = [
    (json.loads(i["data-project"]), i["data-ref"])
    for i in soup.find_all("div")
    if i.get("data-project")
]

for i in data:
    print(f'{i[0]["urls"]["web"]["project"]}?ref={i[1]}')
```

Then you can iterate the pages ("Load more" button) by just incrementing the `page` query parameter

Comment: but how can I get the text in the body of the projects?

Comment: @MaryamRahmaniMoghaddam is this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61536072/how-to-scrape-project-urls-from-indiegogo-using-beautifulsoup) ?

Comment: I thought it might be related to this question. I have asked the new question here. Please help me if you can. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62335537/scraping-text-from-kickstarter-projects-return-nothing