# How to scrape project urls from indiegogo using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: javascript, json, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape project URLs from [Indiegogo](https://www.indiegogo.com/explore/all?project_type=campaign&project_timing=ending_soon&sort=trending), but I had no success after hours. I can not scrape them either using XPath or Beautifulsoup. The output of the following code does not contain the information I want:

```
soup.find_all("div")
```

Also, Beutifulsoup did not work:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.indiegogo.com/explore/all?project_type=campaign&project_timing=ending_soon&sort=trending'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

project_name_list = soup.find(class_='exploreDetail-campaigns row')

project_name_list_items = project_name_list.find_all('a')
print(project_name_list_items)

for project_name in project_name_list_items:
    links = project_name.get('href')
    print(links)
```

Actually, the following command returns nothing.

```
soup.find(class_='exploreDetail-campaigns row')
```

How should I know if a website is in javascript format or another format?

Comment: What you trying to scrap?

Comment: @0m3r, I am trying to scrape project URLs, for example, "https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/nexfan-ultra-portable-ac-with-powerful-cooling#/".